# Can I use go-ipfs directly in my Go program?

Tags: api, go, ipfs

I connect to IPFS via `go-ifps-api` like in this example:

```golang
 import api "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api"

 shell := api.NewShell("localhost:5001")
 cid, err := shell.Add(bytes.NewBufferString("Hello world"))
 ...
 err = shell.Get(cid, "hello.txt")
 ...
```

However, if someone downloads such a program, they have to install `go-ipfs` and also have the 5001 port free. I understand that port can be flexible, but then it is one more complication.

I would like users to connect to IPFS transparently without setting up an API service, so the IPFS node is started and stopped from inside of a Go application.

Is it possible, and if yes, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use go-ipfs as a library. There are some examples here https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/tree/90a573354af23e361da87a29f7bafc459967c070/docs/examples. Basically you need to import `go-ipfs` (and some of its subpackages) instead of `go-ipfs-api`.